# Create a barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Can you help me create the following barplot using the ggplot2 package and the data in the `mat` matrix?

```
mat <- matrix(c(70.93,78.58,78.72,69.24,62.53,43.85,83.49,70.00,78.30,78.11,71.16,63.82,47.37,89.87),ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("Crude","Standardized")
rownames(mat) <- 2006:2012

library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
my_palette <- palette(brewer.pal(7,"Set1"))

barplot2(mat,
main="Crude and Standardized Rates",
xlab="Type", ylab="Rate", xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(40,100),
col=my_palette, beside=TRUE, plot.grid = TRUE, xpd=FALSE)
legend(locator(1), rownames(mat), title ="Year",fill=my_palette)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward ggplot graph. The principle is to melt the data into long form and then map the aesthetics. Applying the brewer color palette is then just a matter of using a scale.

```
library("reshape2")

tmp <- melt(mat)
names(tmp) <- c("Year", "Type", "Rate")

library("ggplot2")

ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Type, y=Rate, fill=factor(Year))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black") +
    scale_fill_brewer(type="qual", palette=1)
```

[image]

EDIT:

In the comments, you asked how to zoom in on the bars, and @joran gave a response that `coord_cartesian` will do that.  But I want to echo his concern. Don't to that. Bars represent their value by area; not starting at 0 means that you are distorting differences. You can change representations to show the differences:

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=Year, y=Rate, colour=Type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

This uses point and lines which represent their value by position which is not distorted when the axis does not include 0.

Comment: Thank you. One of my problems was that I couldn't set the limits of y-axis to c(40,100) as in the plot I posted. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: When I give a "+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(40,100))" the limits are ok but the plot disappears.

Comment: @Brani Use `coord_cartesian` instead. But be aware that only showing the tops of the bars is often considered fairly bad practice among serious graphical experts.

Comment: @joran Thanks. I am aware of that but in this case there are some subtle differences that I want to be distinctive.